# Python filter points in 2D space

Tags: python, arrays, element, multipleselection

I have two arrays `x=[1,2,3,4]` and `y=[1,0,0,1]` describing 2D points (x,y). I want to know how many elements have `x>2` **and** `y==1`. What is the most simple way to do this (without any loops)?
Is it possible to do something like `x[x>2]`, but for two conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are numpy arrays, since your `x[x>2]` is numpy syntax, you just need the and (`&`) operator:

```
meet_cond = (x > 2) & (y == 1)
how_many = meet_cond.sum()

which_x = x[meet_cond]
which_y = y[meet_cond]
```

Comment: Very cool. It might be interesting to show how `meet_cond` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` and `y` belong together as points, you might want to pack them into a `np` 2D array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> xy = np.array([x, y]).T
>>> xy[(x > 2) & (y == 1)]
array([[4, 1]])
>>> xy[(xy[:, 0] > 2) & (xy[:, 1] == 1)]
array([[4, 1]])
>>> np.count_nonzero((xy[:, 0] > 2) & (xy[:, 1] == 1))
1
```